# Como Criar um componente do tipo Web Forms User Control

Tags: asp.net

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu criei um componente do tipo Web Forms User Control, nele coloquei botão, grid, da forma que eu quero que seja o meu cadastro padrão. Ele funciona, desde que seja em uma pagina que esteja no mesmo projeto. Eu gostaria de criar um projeto chamado componentes, pois terei outro projetos que irao usar esse mesmo cadastro padrão. Entao criei um projeto web separado chamado Componentes, gerei uma dll, mas quando tento importar essa dll na minha toolbox aparece a mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando encontrei artigos falando para criar um projeto do tipo class library e adicionar a web form user control nele. Porem nao aparece pra mim esse web forms user control, aparece apenas recursos para windows form.

Alguem sabe o que posso fazer nesse caso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o ToolboxItemAttribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute.aspx

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3829373/194717

Comment: Tony, valeu cara :)

Comment: Caso tenha sido útil, por favor considere aceitar como resposta.

Comment: Eu sou novo no forum, nao tava achando como colocava ehehehe Valeu :)